# How do I select a column which is a concatenation of two columns in the same table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

Column `fieldid` is a concatentation of `EmpId` and `Reason`. Sometimes, due to improperly written code logic, it so happens that the concatenation does not happen properly, and it uses a different `EmpId` than the one belonging to the current record.

How do I find out such errant records?

I have tried this, but needless to stay, its stupid.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE fieldid IN (SELECT Empid + Reason FROM EmployeeAttendance)
```

I am using SQL SERVER 2008. `Empid`, `Reason` and `fieldid` are varchars.

Thanks.

Comment: SQL-Server: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE fieldid <> Empid + Reason OR fieldid IS NULL`. Replace `+` with `||` for Oracle and MySQL.

Comment: @ypercube Right, your query makes sense. But I am also getting records which satisfy the condition I mentioned above. Datatypes at play?

Comment: @ypercube Could you state your comment as an answer? I would like to accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL-server:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableX 
WHERE fieldid <> Empid + Reason 
   OR fieldid IS NULL     AND (Empid + Reason) IS NOT NULL
   OR fieldid IS NOT NULL AND (Empid + Reason) IS NULL ;
```